Add Action Key Objects based on User Action
I'm working with Angular 18 and reactive forms. When I receive data from the backend, the form gets pre-filled.
Below is the backend response:


InitialResponse =  {
    "FS_Application": {
        "STATUS": "DRAFT",
        "FS_Applicant_Details": [
            {
                "FS_Applicant": {
                    "APPLICANT_NAME": "POTENCY COMMUNICATIONS (PTY) LTD",
                }
            }
        ],
        "FS_RequestType_Details": {
            "FS_RequestType": [
                {
                    "FLOW": "",
                    "SEQUENCE_NUMBER": "",
                    "FS_Beneficiary_Details": {
                        "FS_Beneficiary": [
                            {
                                "ZAR_AMOUNT": "100.00",
                                "FS_Beneficiary_Id": {
                                    "Id": "16422",
                                    "ItemId": "005056A62B4EA1EF8FBFE9478FED8856.16422"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "FLOW": "",
                    "FS_Beneficiary_Details": {
                        "FS_Beneficiary": [
                            {
                                "ZAR_AMOUNT": "2000.00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}



Users can perform actions like modifying the data, deleting an FS_Beneficiary, or adding a new FS_Beneficiary.
The updated form data is stored in CurrentResponse.
Now, I need to compare the InitialResponse with CurrentResponse and create a payload for the backend API.
I need to add an "OPERATION" key with values such as 'UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'CREATE', or 'SKIP' based on the user's modifications.
For example, if the "STATUS" is modified to "REVIEW":


newPayLoadRequest = {
    "FS_Application": {
        "OPERATION": "UPDATE",
        "STATUS": "REVIEW"
    }
}



If there is no change in the status:


newPayLoadRequest = {
    "FS_Application": {
        "OPERATION": "SKIP",
        "STATUS": "DRAFT"
    }
}



The "OPERATION" key should be added to all parent objects.
For FS_Beneficiary:
If a new item is added, set "OPERATION": "CREATE".
If an existing FS_Beneficiary with an FS_Beneficiary_Id key is deleted, set "OPERATION": "DELETE".


"FS_Beneficiary_Details": {
 "OPERATION": "UPDATED",
  "FS_Beneficiary": [{
    "OPERATION": "CREATED",
    "ZAR_AMOUNT": "2000.00"
  }]
}



Can anyone help me create this payload request?
Angular Code,


if (this.data ? .isEdit) {
  this.viewService.viewSubmissionData$.subscribe(res => {
    if (res) {

      const FS_RequestType_Details = res ? .fsApplication ? .fsRequestTypeDetails ? .fsRequestType ? .map((requestType: any) => ({
        Title: {
          Value: requestType ? .title ? .value || ""
        },
        FS_Request_Type_Id: {
          Id: requestType ? .fsRequestTypeId ? .id || "",
          ItemId: requestType ? .fsRequestTypeId ? .itemId || ""
        },

        Flow: requestType ? .flow || "",
        Sequence_Number: requestType ? .sequenceNumber || "",
        FS_Beneficiary_Details: {
          FS_Beneficiary: requestType ? .fsBeneficiaryDetails ? .fsBeneficiary ? .map((beneficiary: any) => ({
            Title: {
              Value: beneficiary ? .title ? .value || ""
            },
            FS_Beneficiary_Id: {
              Id: beneficiary ? .fsBeneficiaryId ? .id || "",
              ItemId: beneficiary ? .fsBeneficiaryId ? .itemId || ""
            },
            Beneficiary_Name: beneficiary ? .beneficiaryName || "",

          })) || []
        }
      })) || [];


      const editApplicationRequestPlayload = {
        "FS_Application": {
          "FS_Application-id": {
            "Id": res ? .fsApplication ? .fsApplicationId ? .id,
            "ItemId": res ? .fsApplication ? .fsApplicationId ? .itemId
          },
          "APPLICANT_NAME": res ? .fsApplication ? .applicantName,

          "FS_Applicant_Details": [

          ],
          FS_RequestType_Details
        }
      };
      console.log('original', editApplicationRequestPlayload);

      this.newApplicationServ.getFinalPayload().subscribe(([reInfo$, stepOne, stepTwo, stepThree, stepFour]) => {
        const FS_RequestType = stepTwo.map((group: any) => {

          const beneficiaries = stepTwo.beneficiaries.map((beneficiary: any) => ({
            "BENEFICIARY_NAME": beneficiary.name,

          }));

          return {
            "FLOW": '',
            "SEQUENCE_NUMBER": '',
            "FS_Beneficiary_Details": {
              "FS_Beneficiary": beneficiaries
            }
          };
        });

        const FS_RequestType_Details = {
          "FS_RequestType": FS_RequestType
        };

        const currentRequestPayload = {
          "FS_Application": {

            "STATUS": "DRAFT",
            "FS_Applicant_Details": [{
              "FS_Applicant": {
                "APPLICANT_NAME": stepOne ? .applicantName,
              }
            }],
            "FS_RequestType_Details": FS_RequestType_Details
          }
        };

        const final = this.comparePayloads(editApplicationRequestPlayload, currentRequestPayload);

      });
    }
  });
}



